# WebBrower in c#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am trying to click on a button in some website using c# code and it's code from the inspector:

```
<td colspan="1" rowspan="1" align="left"><table class="t10Button" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" summary="">
<tbody><tr>
<td class="t10L"><a href="javascript:apex.submit('LOGIN');"><img src="/i/themes/theme_10_ar/button_left.gif" alt="" width="4" height="24"></a></td>
<td class="t10C"><a href="javascript:apex.submit('LOGIN');">Sign-in</a></td>
<td class="t10R"><a href="javascript:apex.submit('LOGIN');"><img src="/i/themes/theme_10_ar/button_right.gif" width="4" height="24" alt=""></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table></td>
```

My code looks something like this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("t10C").InvokeMember("submit");
```

But I have failed: Nothing happens when the code gets executed.

Comment: "I have failed" is not a sufficient error description.

Comment: I don't see any element with the `id` of `"javascript:apex.submit('LOGIN');"`

Comment: actually nothing happens when the code get executed.

Comment: yes there is not, so how to retrieve the element without an id?

Comment: Maybe try InvokeScript directly? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.invokescript(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < webBrowser1.Document.Links.Count; i++)

if (webBrowser1.Document.Links[i].GetAttribute("href") == "javascript:apex.submit('LOGIN');")  
{
 webBrowser1.Document.Links[i].InvokeMember("Click");  
}
```

It will click on a link if it's url is `javascript:apex.submit('LOGIN');`.

Comment: yes that worked for me, thanks alot, but what about a table element?  like this: `<td><a href="f?p=134:14:1168788664179308::NO:::"><img src="/i/menu/instructor_wbg_64x64.png" border="0"></a><br><a href="f?p=134:14:1168788664179308::NO:::"><div style="width:150px">‎Student Information System</div></a></td>` I want to click on it, but the same method doesn't work, so what is the problem?

Comment: @O-BL Please tell me what you have made so far and what are you trying to do? You want to click on the link again?

Comment: Actually I am trying to get the courses that my university site offer to let me pick some of them easily for the next semester and here is my code so far:

Comment: `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("P101_USERNAME").InnerText = "myID";
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("P101_PASSWORD").InnerText = "myPass";
                foreach (HtmlElement Link in webBrowser1.Document.Links)
                {
                    if (Link.GetAttribute("href") == "javascript:apex.submit('LOGIN');")
                    {
                        Link.InvokeMember("Click");
                        break;
                    }
                }`

Comment: after I have loged-in I want to enter another link that is presented in the java-script above.

Comment: this is the way the code works : It looks for a link with a specific url and Invokes its click event.So you need to change the url each time you need to click on a link with new url.